# How to update/flash android emulator with the latest build

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I am new in all this android emulator subject and have seen one issue that I can't figure out how is the correct procedure to build and update the emulator with the latest build and other supporting files like *.rc, *.te..

For example, I have a hello-world module in C++ that has the below files:

[image]

My module is successfully building with mma (in hello path) and also make is successful (in android path).

The emulator is also running but I see that when I edit files like *.rc or *.te and do a mma again on the emulator I still see the old version of those files. This happens also for the binary file of hello and sometimes I have to push the new binary into the adb device to /data/ folder since only this one is read/write for me.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is wrong with pushing the binary to /data/ folder? If you want to modify the emulator image you have to unpack the system image offline (without running emulator), modify it, repack it and then create an new emulator instance from the new image. Usually it is not worth the effort building a new emulator image unless make changes to core system components (kernel, services, ...)

Comment: I know that for example my `hello.rc` should go to `/vendor/etc/init/` can I push it to `/data/` too and it will work? And what about *.te files or other sepoilcy files? I also know that the hello binary can be pushed and used from /data/.